# Convergence of a sequence in $l_2$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am wanting to disprove (show that it is not the case) that for a sequence ${x_n} = x^n$, ($n\in\mathbb N$), that if $(x_i)^n \to x_i$ in $\mathbb R$,then $x^n\to x$ in $\ell_2$. I have gotten as far as using the $\ell_2$ norm to attempt to show that it doesn't converge, but I am somehow stuck. 
I have gone ahead and stated that if we get that $(x_i)^n \to 0$ as n approaches infinity, then $\sqrt{({\sum_{n}^{} ({x^n-0})^2})}$, but I am not getting  much after this. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Edit:
${x_n}$ is a sequence in $l_2$ equal to $x^n$, which is the n-th power. The index $i$ ranges from $i=1,2,3,...$. Thus, $(x_i)^n$ denotes the n-th power of the i-th coordinate.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What is $x_n$? What is $x^n$? The n-th power? The index? What is $(x_i)^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Point-wise convergence in $l_2$ (which is what I understood you are talking about) is a weaker condition than convergence in norm. Since convergence in norm implies point-wise convergence, the best way to answer your question is to find a counter-example (or show that it exists), since what you are trying to prove can be true in some particular cases.

Here is such an example:
Let $x_i = 2^{-i}$ for $i=1,2,\dots$ . Then $\Vert x \Vert^2 = \sum_i 2^{-2i} < \infty$, so $x \in l_2$.

Since $\lim_n x_i^n = 0$, we have that $x^n$ converges point-wise to $0$. But
$$ \Vert x^n \Vert = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-2in} \right)^{1/2} = \left( \frac{4^n}{4^n - 1} \right)^{1/2} \to 1 $$
and therefore $x^n$ can not converge in norm to $0$.